# Unity canvas rect shows in game mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

After adding a `GameObject -> UI -> button` to my Unity canvas, when in game mode the canvas rectangle is showing up when I don't want to see it. It should only be visible in scene mode. How do I ensure that it is not visible in game mode?

Comment: can you post a snapshot of canvas setting in inspector?

Answer (score 7):

Check if Gizmos is On. Turn it Off and outlining rectangle would not be visible in GameMode. Or it can be an Image component attached to canvas if you are talking about filled rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out that when i built the game on android the canvas rect is not invisible (it is only visible in unity editor).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation as this answer is not entirely clear.